# Using Bind Variables for Dynamic SQL Update

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an update statement in dynamic sql like this:

```
varDynQuery := 'UPDATE TABLE SET B0 = ' || A0;

IF(A1 IS NOT NULL) THEN
 varDynQuery := varDynQuery || ', B1 = ' || A1;
END IF;

IF(A2 IS NOT NULL) THEN
 varDynQuery := varDynQuery || ', B2 = ' || A2;
END IF;
```

I would like to change it to use bind variables instead to prevent SQL injection

```
varDynQuery := 'UPDATE TABLE SET B0 = :A0';

IF(A1 IS NOT NULL) THEN
 varDynQuery := varDynQuery || ', B1 = :A1';
END IF;

IF(A2 IS NOT NULL) THEN
 varDynQuery := varDynQuery || ', B2 = :A2';
END IF;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varDynQuery USING
A0, A1, A2;
```

However, due to the fact that A1 and A2 are not always going to be present, it can cause an error during the procedure runtime.

Is there any way to shape the SQL statement such that all variables can be bound successfully without updating those that need to be excluded?

Note: Would like to avoid using coalesce.

Comment: I assume by `A1 != ""` you mean `A1 is not null` and by `varDynQuery : ` you mean `varDynQuery := varDynQuery || `.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make sure that all bind variables are included, e.g.:

```
varDynQuery := 'UPDATE TABLE SET B0 = :A0,
  B1 = NVL(:A1,B1),
  B2 = NVL(:A2,B2)';

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varDynQuery USING
A0, A1, A2;
```

The advantage of this approach is that there is only one query that needs to be parsed, meaning less load on the shared pool.

The only downside is that if you have any column-specific triggers, they will fire for B1 and B2 even if they're not being changed.

If that's a problem, you would need to use a different execute immediate for each of the four update scenarios (e.g. B0; B0+B1; B0+B2; B0+B1+B2)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is this one:

```
varDynQuery := 'UPDATE TABLE SET B0 = :A0';

IF(A1 IS NOT NULL) THEN
 varDynQuery := varDynQuery || ', B1 = :A1';
END IF;

IF(A2 IS NOT NULL) THEN
 varDynQuery := varDynQuery || ', B2 = :A2';
END IF;

IF A1 IS NOT NULL THEN
    IF A2 IS NOT NULL THEN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varDynQuery USING A0, A1, A2;
    ELSE
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varDynQuery USING A0, A1;
    END IF;
ELSE
    IF A2 IS NOT NULL THEN
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varDynQuery USING A0, A2;
    ELSE
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE varDynQuery USING A0;
    END IF;
END IF;
```

However, your code is getting crowed if you have more variables than just 2-3.